# After sDNA integration analysis, the integration results of radius N and 500 are consistent, and the coordinate system is WGS84 Mercator projection

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sdna

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

After sDNA integration analysis, the integration results of radius N and 500 are consistent, and the coordinate system is WGS84 Mercator projection

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is as you would expect - in WGS84 coordinates, a radius of 500 degrees covers the whole world (and more) so is equivalent to the global radius N.

To get an analysis using a 500 metre radius, reproject the data to a suitable local coordinate system with a grid measured in metres, then rerun sDNA.

Comment: Hello, I re-projected the Bejing54 coordinate system, but the result is still the same. Is there any other reason for this result?

Comment: Maybe some other preparation error: are the link lengths output by sDNA (LLen) and link connectivities (LConn) as you would expect? see also https://sdna-open.readthedocs.io/en/latest/network_preparation.html